# Android Facebook Developers Can't "Save Changes" on "Sample App Settings" for "Android Key Hash"

Tags: android, facebook, hash, save, key

Hi Stackoverflow community,

I logged into developers.facebook.com and am trying to hit "Save Changes" on the "Sample App Settings" for "Android Key Hash". (After typing in an Android Key Hash)

[image: Facebook Picture]

I have saved two other Android key hashes in the past (because I switched computers/ struggled to find the right key hash), but now I can't add a third key hash.

My first guess was that the key has I found was invalid, but it's the one I got from following the directions at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook/, so I doubt it.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

try {
    PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
        "com.replaced.with.my.pakage.name.here", 
        PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
    for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
        md.update(signature.toByteArray());
        Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
        }
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

}
...
```

I seem to have been locked out? Any thoughts on how to resolve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to fix this, but I learned you don't actually need to post the android key hash in this section-- you can just put them in on an app by app basis via the App Dashboard.

On this page:
[image: Facebook Android Key Hashes]

I used the following tutorials:

```
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook/
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/scrumptious/authenticate/
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/scrumptious/personalize/
```

Good luck!

Comment: The dialog in "Sample App Settings" is only there so you can use the sample apps that ship with the SDK. For your own apps, you should definitely put them in the app dashboard.

Answer (score 2):

I realized that the number of characters in the hash key that I got from Facebook and that generated using the keytool command was not the same, because I which the Save Changes button was not getting enabled.. I added the last character of the longer to the shorter one and it worked